# Lost the source to minified Javascript. What Angular package uses "require.register"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, bundling-and-minification

[This file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CEBFD2A18B036D51!9419&authkey=!AAQIyh5ts6sBeJ8&ithint=folder%2Cjs) consists of many different Angular packages combined together. The original source has been lost and I need to backtrace and figure out what was used, or get this code to a maintainable position.

From subsequent, non minified code, I've been able to infer that these libraries are contained within:

- Angular
- Angular Animate
- Breadcrumb
- Content Editable
- JWT
- Local Storage
- QR Code
- UI Router
- ng file upload
- Restangular
- Require.js
- ?? about 6  others I haven't yet identified.

What minified code within that library would call the code below.  It fails saying

> `Uncaught TypeError: require.register is not a function(anonymous function) @ views-Bbmo8.js:3

```
require.register("common/views/appleSearch", function(exports, require, module) {
    module.exports = "<div class=popover><div class=arrow></div><div class=popover-content><div class=form-group><label translate>Search for an App</label><input placeholder=\"{{'Enter app name'|translate}}\" ng-change=searchApp($parent.appleSearch) ng-model=$parent.appleSearch ng-model-options=\"{ debounce: 200 }\" class=form-control></div><hr data-ng-show=\"appleResults.length &gt; 0\"><ul class=list-unstyled><li data-ng-repeat=\"result in appleResults\" class=\"app-item clearfix\"><div class=pull-left><img ng-src={{result.artworkUrl60}} ng-if=result.artworkUrl60></div><div class=\"name-container pull-left\"><div class=app-name>{{ result.trackCensoredName | limitTo:20}}</div><div class=company-name>{{ result.sellerName | limitTo:20}}</div></div><button data-ng-click=setApp(result) translate class=\"btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right\">Select</button></li></ul></div></div>";
});
```

Comment: Ouch, you might try [an unminifier](http://unminify.com/), they kind of suck, but they might help you out.  This might be requirejs, or an older version.

Comment: Or it could be angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$animateProvider#register